# Why does to_ascii_lowercase return a String rather than a Cow<str>?

Tags: string, rust, api-design, copy-on-write

[`str::to_ascii_lowercase`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.str.html#method.to_ascii_lowercase) returns a String. Why doesn't it return a [`Cow<str>`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/borrow/enum.Cow.html) just like [`to_string_lossy`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.str.html?search=to_string_lossy) or [`String::from_utf8_lossy`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/string/struct.String.html#method.from_utf8_lossy)?

The same applies to [`str::to_ascii_uppercase`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.str.html#method.to_ascii_uppercase).

Answer (score 2):

The reason why you might want to return a `Cow<str>` presumably is because the string may *already* be lower case. However, to detect this edge case might also introduce a performance degradation when the string is not already lower case, which intuitively seems like the most common scenario.

You can, of course, create your own function that wraps `to_ascii_lowercase()`, checks if it is already lower case, and return a `Cow<str>`:

```
fn my_to_ascii_lowercase<'a>(s: &'a str) -> Cow<'a, str> {
    let bytes = s.as_bytes();
    if !bytes.iter().any(u8::is_ascii_uppercase) {
        Cow::Borrowed(s)
    } else {
        Cow::Owned(s.to_ascii_lowercase())
    }
}
```

Comment: This was my first thought, but you have to check the edge case anyway: While iterating over the string slice, you have to check every single character. For now, the `String` is allocated before and then it loops over every letter. It's changed when needed. You could just search for the first occurrence of a upper cased letter: `str.chars().position(|c| !c.is_lowercase())`. If nothing is found, you return `Cow::Borrow`, otherwise you start converting to lower case from this point.

Comment: More or less [this](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=159c238a86a453aa217aabb5d3936bb9&version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015)